# Problem updating 8.10 Intrepid to 9.04 Jaunty using do-release-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 9.04, 8.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Wondering if anyone has run into this. I'm trying to do a "do-release-upgrade" and what I receive is:

An upgrade from 'intrepid' to 'karmic' is not supported with this tool. I realize you can't go from 8.10 to 10.04, but I'd like to go from intrepid to jaunty.

I've made sure all of the packages are up to date.