# How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, repository, release-management, support

Recently I have installed an older version of Ubuntu on my old machine. Whenever I try to install any software, I get an error saying it couldn't be found:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done               
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done    
E: Couldn't find package vlc
```

Comment: It might be worth editing some (or all) answers to this question, as during the weekend after spending quite a while trying to make this work I have by luck realized that they have moved over from `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` to `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` (or your own respective two letter abbreviated county code at the beginning) starting from 17.10 (essentially in sync with going back to the beginning of the alphabet).

Comment: They deliberately do this in order to break older releases and force you to upgrade

Comment: Upgrading from Artful to Bionic in 2020, I found that `us.archive.` did not work, but `old-releases.` did.

Comment: Try to upgrade your release, e.g. `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: **Upgrading EOL Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04** I upgraded Ubuntu using the GUI program "Software Updater" in a simpler way without manually updating any of the system file as suggested by the earlier responses in this post. That too many months after EOL of Ubuntu 21.10.

Note: The procedure given in https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start throw an error "404 Not Found" mostly because my /etc/apt/sources.list was referring to the defunct links. Whereas, the GUI  approach approached successfully.

Answer (score 755, accepted):

The repositories for older releases that are not supported (like 11.04, 11.10 and 13.04) get moved to an archive server. There are repositories available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.

The reason for this is that it is now out of support and no longer receiving updates and security patches.

I would urge you to consider a supported distribution. If your computer is too old in terms of memory or processor then you should consider a distribution such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

If you want to continue using an outdated release then edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

You can do this with `sed`:

```bsh
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then update with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Sometimes, it might be faster to create backups of your system and reinstall using supported release instead.

Source: [Can I keep using Ubuntu 9.04 if it's outdated?](https://askubuntu.com/q/90929/507051)

---

### To upgrade to a new release:

Once you have performed the above steps to switch to the old-releases mirrors, update the Update Manager and then do `do-release-upgrade`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

See also [EOLUpgrades - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/).

Comment: and, just for the sake of completeness... what about `extras` repository (for Skype etc)? Are they available anywhere after EOF?

Comment: an easier way is `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` and modify it manually. I had to do it because I'm quite new and I don't know sed to make this work for karmic, Thanks, Your answer is still valid and correct.

Comment: An even easier way is `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, as `vi*` is just annoying...

Comment: @TomášZato, until someone can answer the bits about extras.ubuntu.com, you can comment out the particular lines to proceed with other apt-get uses.

Comment: The `sed` command doesn't always work, as there are mirrors that are run by organizations outside of `ubuntu.com`. I'm not even sure that there are three dots for all of the domain names. For those, you must manually edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: There is an issue with this in upgrading from 15.04 as of 3/21/17. Vivid is no longer supported, however the dist is not on old-releases.

Comment: Doesn't work; I'm trying to install a program on Ubuntu 16.10. Everything is switched to the old-releases URL's; those give 404.

Comment: What about `archive.canonical.com`? I'm assuming it does not need to change.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Olathe You could do this instead: `sed -i 's|/archive.canonical|archive.canonical|g;s|http://.*/ubuntu|http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu|g;s|archive.canonical|/archive.canonical|g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: This solution doesn't allow to upgrade if the next release is not supported (i.e. it works if you are in the first unsupported release or firs unsupported LTS release).

See **Upgrade a very old ubuntu** bellow.

Comment: For releases in 2020, this answer gave me everything I needed: https://askubuntu.com/a/1212699/325562 - things have changed since these answers were written and they aren't valid for, say, 18.10 to 19.04.

Comment: this answer (especiall the sed-part) still works on impish,which became unsupported recently

Comment: *Note to Raspberry Pi users:* your original sources.list entry will have `/ubuntu-ports/` at the end of the repository URL. The old-releases server does *not* have a separate directory for other architectures, everything just lives under `/ubuntu/` there. So in addition to replacing the domain with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, you also need to REMOVE the `-ports` from the end of the URL. I had this issue in my question here and ended up figuring it out on my own: https://askubuntu.com/a/1423627/1585621

Comment: For me only this solution worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385440/ubuntu-sudo-apt-get-update-404-not-found-problem

Answer (score 138):

## [What are 404 errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)

> The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code
>   indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server,
>   but the server could not find what was requested.
>
> The web site hosting server will typically generate "404 - Page Not
>   Found" web page, when users attempts to follow a broken or dead link.

## Why are we facing 404 errors

Ubuntu follows the approach of two different [release cycles](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases):

> **Normal Ubuntu releases** are supported for 9 months. **LTS releases** are supported for 5 years.
>
> Past releases may have different support schedules (for example, normal releases (before 13.04) used to be supported for 18 months, while LTS releases (before 12.04) used to be supported for 3 years on the desktop and 5 years on the server).

**EOL:** Once the support period for a particular release is over; they are called [End Of Life (EOL)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) and all the updates and package repositories for that Release are transferred to a different server which results in 404 errors while running `sudo apt-get update`. You can confirm if your release has become EOL by going to [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29). If your Ubuntu release is mentioned under "End Of Life (EOL)" Table, then the release is no longer supported and you should try to upgrade to a [newer supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable). However, if you wish to continue using this unsupported release, you would have to make necessary modifications in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to the `old-releases` server of Ubuntu.

## Steps to make necessary modifications

1. Open your Terminal:

   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>; OR
   - If you have Gnome: `Applications` → `Accessories` → `Terminal`; OR
   - If you have Unity: press <kbd>Super</kbd> (the key between <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>) and query for `Terminal`.
2. Run the following command to enter into root shell:

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```

   input your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The prompt would change and would indicate that the root user is now logged in. Here run the following command:

   ```
   gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. The file would open in a new Gedit window. Find the first line which ***doesn't*** start with `#`. Suppose you are running Karmic Koala (Ubuntu 9.10): it should be like the following line:

   ```
   deb <siteurl> karmic main restricted
   ```

   where, `<siteurl>` is your preferred server - `http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` in your case (for example).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to replace your `<siteurl>` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

   - Search for: `http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` ie; `<siteurl>`
   - Replace with: `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and
   - Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
5. Once again:

   - Search for: `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` (this exact url for all the Ubuntu Releases — whatever be the present server that you are using)
   - Replace with: `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`
   - Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
6. Save your file and exit Gedit.
7. Run the following command to get out of root shell:

   ```
   logout
   ```

   You would find that the prompt switches back to indicate that your normal user is now logged in. Then run the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

There you go. No 404 Errors this time. You can now install all the available packages for your Ubuntu Release. You can also run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to install any Security/Bug-fix updates which have not yet been installed but you won't get any further Security/Bug-fix updates from Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for also including instructions to update the security repo.

Comment: Actually the first line without a # was `raring main restricted`, no deb whatsoever. I changed it as specified, and then also replaced the urls, but still got 404s.

Comment: @Yokhen If the line didn't begin with `deb <siteurl>`, then most likely your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file has become corrupted due to some reason. Please follow the answers given at: 
[How do I restore the default repositories?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories). That would restore the correct `/etc/apt/sources.list` for you and then follow my answer to change the servers to point to the old-releases server.

Comment: thanks! Somehow I managed to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 though, and now I'm on my way to 14.04.

Comment: In newer Ubuntu versions, `gksu` is no longer installed by default. And since the release would be EOL at this point, users won't be able to install it. It may be better to use `nano` or `vim` instead, with a normal `sudo` command. `gksu` may start causing confusion like in the following question:   http://askubuntu.com/questions/797422/how-to-install-gksu-on-15-04

Comment: @Dan, modified the answer, now we enter into root shell and then run the graphical program. No need to use gksudo anymore. I want to keep this answer for the novice users like me and don't want to complicate matters with using terminal based editors, however easy or powerful they may be.

Comment: @Yokhen You've probably figured this out, but if anyone else is seeing the same thing, I'd be willing to bet that you've got text wrapping turned on, and the window is too small.  Just increase the window size, and it'll look fine.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me upgrade from Zesty to Artful. :-)

Comment: This also fixed an issue I had when upgrading from Zesty to Artful.. (I think the initial upgrade only half worked and I didn't notice)

Comment: Aren't there any repercussions after changing the sources.list file manually?

Comment: @aderchox It's safe to manually edit `sources.list`. Just make sure to not make any mistake. And if `apt` complaints about any error, then fix the mistake and re-run the `apt` command :-)

Comment: Not working. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/webkit2gtk/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37_2.28.2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb still gives not found

Answer (score 65):

The short answer is to add the next apt repository to the **Third-Party Software** (or **Other Software**  in newer versions) in **Software Sources** (or **Software & Updates** in newer versions):

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu code_name main restricted universe multiverse
```

The long answer...

## GUI Method

Well, actually we will do this without using any [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal). Not even once. Just GUI, *I promise ;-)*

First, open **Software Sources** (or **Software & Updates** in newer versions). It does not matter how old your Ubuntu is, there is certainly something like this. For Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope), look at next image to see where it's located:

[image: Open Software Sources]

After **Software Sources** (or **Software & Updates**) is open, go in **Ubuntu Software** and **Updates** tabs and unselect everything like in next pictures. You don't need these things anymore since your Ubuntu version is [End of Life](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/):

[image: Ubuntu Software tab]

---

[image]

Without closing **Software Sources** (or **Software & Updates**), go in **Third-Party Software** (for newest releases, this tab is named **Other Software**) tab and add a new apt repository. Insert exactly next line when you are asked:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jaunty main restricted universe multiverse
```

If your version of Ubuntu is not 9.04, replace in the above line `jaunty` with your Ubuntu codename (for example, if you have Ubuntu 9.10, replace it with `karmic` and so on):

[image: Third-Party Software tab]

Now, when you will close **Software Sources** (or **Software & Updates**), you will be asked to reload the information about available software. Just be sure that you have a working internet connection:

[image: Reload available software]

---

[image: Downloading available software]

And now, you are free to download almost whatever you want. For 9.04, you can use **Synaptic Package Manager**. For newest releases, there is **Ubuntu Software Center**.

For example, to install VLC in Ubuntu 9.04 using Synaptic Package Manager, follow the instructions in the following pictures:

[image: Open Synaptic Package Manager]

---

[image: Search VLC in SPM]

---

[image: Mark VLC]

---

[image: Mark additional VLC]

---

[image: Apply VLC]

---

[image: Download VLC]

---

[image: Open VLC]

If you want to Update your Ubuntu to a new release, just go to **System** > **Update Manager**:

[image: Update Manager]

---

[image: Upgrade]

I tested this method from a live session of Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) and as you can see from these pictures it worked. If you are on an installed session of Ubuntu, you will be asked sometimes for root or admin password. Just insert your personal user password when you are asked.

Comment: I just did all this from installed 10.10 (maverick) version. Everything well good as described. @Radu, your answer is flawless!

Comment: Those images needs updating... wait... what are you doing with a pre-12.04?

Comment: @Braiam Those images are up to date. If you will give a try to [Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope)](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/9.04/), you will understand.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Ubuntu 9.04 was my first foray into the linux world. Ahh, those screenshots bring back memories!

Comment: Cannot get this to work for 15.04 to be upgraded to 16.04. Can't get past adding the new APT line please help.

Comment: @MrMule, check my answer below, maybe it will do the trick for you.

Comment: I am thankful for the answer, however it might be in my opinion a little too much verbose, I am not going to read and study all the 15 screenshots, which change rapidly by time, maybe if there were half -7 screenshots, just to find out it would not work for my case and fail in the end. When there are 10 other responses to the question.

Comment: I found the working solution in this question, so I thought I would add a single one-liner shortcut what I have studied here as an answer, but since it did not pass through, I would at least post it as a comment if it could help anyone ```release=bionic; cat > "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/$release.list"<<EOF
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release-security main
EOF``` and execute after the command `sudo apt update`, or feel free to handle this comment as you find best

Answer (score 33):

I got here since I could not upgrade a system from 15.10 (EOL) to 16.04. But none of the answers worked for me, even after doing everything that was suggested here I kept getting from `sudo do-release-upgrade` the annoying response:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release  
No new release found
```

And I had no success in running `update-manager`; it kept throwing exceptions which I could not resolve. I suspect something is corrupted in my 15.10 installation, but the bottom line is that the built-in upgrades just fail.

So I looked for a non-built-in method, and sure enough I found it looking at [What does `do-release-upgrade` really do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/409555/206303).

Here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Open http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
2. Locate the release you want to upgrade to. In my case it was Xenial Xerus (16.04 Long Term Support). You can find the corresponding codenames on [Release - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).
3. Locate the UpgradeTool URL. For `xenial` it was http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/xenial.tar.gz. Download the tarball from that URL into an empty folder and and extract it.
4. Locate the executable file with the same name as the distribution (in my case `xenial`). Run it with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo ./xenial &
   ```
5. Approve the upgrade, and wait for the download to complete - there's thousands of files and likely over a Gigabyte. Proceed with installing the upgrade.
6. Wait until it completes, approve if asked. I don't recall the exact details
7. After the reboot the new version is running successfully, and all updates can be fetched normally.

Comment: It took me a while to find this post. Only using the referenced tarball I succeeded in getting the upgrade running from 15.04 / wily. The approaches using the old-releases urls did not work. I hope this helps other users getting into this problem.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful!

Comment: Seriously thanks for this, I just used these steps to upgrade 10.04 to 12.04. My issue was different in that my install wasn't corrupted, but there was an error on do-release-upgrade which I was unable to find in the terminal. Following these steps popped up a dialog telling me "error authenticating some packages" which led me to http://askubuntu.com/a/426121/262601 which DID allow the upgrade to continue successfully. Was pulling my hair out, but its my own fault for not upgrading sooner.

Comment: Unfortunately, not even this works for 15.04

Comment: Works as a charm! I had a zesty server that i neglected and I got it to artful and could upgrade further from there, thanks!

Comment: This still works well! [I had to fix the 17.10 URL from the `meta-release` file, which isn't updated to `old-releases`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166905/22949), but that's usually unnecessary. I recommend that users who encounter problems ensure the upgrade was *at some point* supported--[one of these situations](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430/22949) or [that situation](https://askubuntu.com/q/719465/22949)--and also consider combining this with the *preparation* other answers suggest, like enabling the *old-releases* server and upgrading all packages within the current release before starting.

Comment: Will this take me to 22.04 from 19.10?

Answer (score 22):

To get `apt-get` working again, change your software sources to the old release repositories.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

delete whatever is in there, and paste the following:

```
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever, but the result is the same when I try "apt-get install lm-sensors". Maybe there's another missing source:                                              

"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package lm-sensors is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package lm-sensors has no installation candidate"

Comment: Here are the debs: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors-3/. I trust it, you've reloaded the sources list, right?

Comment: This answer does not work... Why does it have so many upvotes? Did anybody actually test it?

Comment: I've tested it, but the real question is: Why are you still on Karmic? It's been out of support for years, and you should really move on to a more recent release.

Comment: This helped me after many other dead ends.  One thing not mentioned is that you'll need to correct any urls inside the sources list files.  the version number in the url has to match the ubuntu version name.

Answer (score 15):

While [*fossfreedom*'s answer does a good job of describing and solving the problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/), I've found a variant solution that I think is easier and a little more elegant.

The trick is to add `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` as a *mirror*, and then tell Software Sources to switch to that mirror.

To do this, backup and edit `/usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.mirrors`. Choose a fake location for the old-releases server (e.g. `#LOC:US`), and add the following line under it:

```
#LOC:US
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

Now open the system's Software Sources dialog, and manually select `old-releases.ubuntu.com` as though it were your regional mirror. You should find it listed under the fake location you chose in the previous step.

The next time you reload your package information via Synaptic or Update Manager, you should see it successfully retrieving updated package information.

Comment: Works fine, very easy & quick

Answer (score 13):

## Upgrade a very old Ubuntu

If your Ubuntu ([Kubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu), [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu), [Mythbuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythbuntu), whatever-buntu) is really old, you will have to take three steps to upgrade to an up-to-date version:

1. Hack the package updater (APT) to upgrade your system to the latest available in the *old-releases* repository (including the release upgrade manager).
2. Hack the release upgrade manager to make it agree to upgrade to the next (officially unsupported) release.
3. Do the actual release upgrade (and repeat).

Remember, you are only allowed to upgrade from one "normal" release to the next and from a Long Time Support (LTS) release to the next LTS release.

### Update the system to the newest available in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com

#### Set the package sources to old-releases.ubuntu.com and update

```bash
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.save
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
```

Here you can try a release upgrade if your current release is not too old (`sudo do-release-upgrade`). If it fails, you may find some clues in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` which could help to find a fix.

If your release is too old, go to next step.

### Configure the release upgrade manager with local data

#### Retrieve the meta-release files

```bash
wget -O - http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release  > meta-release
wget -O - http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts  > meta-release-lts
```

#### Edit meta-release to set all the next releases as supported

You must set `Supported: 1` for each release.

Example: I was on [Ubuntu 17.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_17.04_.28Zesty_Zapus.29) (Zesty Zapus) and set all the releases supported starting from artful.

```
Dist: artful
Name: Artful Aardvark
Version: 17.10
Date: Thu, 19 October 2017 17:10:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 17.10 release
Release-File: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/EOLReleaseAnnouncement
UpgradeTool: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/artful.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/artful.tar.gz.gpg
…
```

Also, check that the URLs for `UpgradeTool` and `UpgradeToolSignature` start with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com` (not `http://archive.ubuntu.com`).

#### Edit `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` to point on local meta-release

Replace the original URIs with URIs pointing on your local meta-release files

```
[METARELEASE]
URI = file:///home/chris/meta-release
URI_LTS = file:///home/chris/meta-release-lts
URI_UNSTABLE_POSTFIX = -development
URI_PROPOSED_POSTFIX = -proposed
```

### Upgrade

```bash
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
```

Reboot when asked to.

Redo it until your system is up to date.

When asked, answer that you want to keep your edited version of `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` excepted on the last upgrade.

### When you are stuck to an old release

The process described above worked for me to upgrade to an unsupported release, and then to the last LTS release and I couldn't upgrade anymore.

What I did: Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) → Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) → [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver)

Then I found the `-p` (`--proposed`) option of `do-release-upgrade`.

```bash
do-release-upgrade -p
```

It tries to upgrade to the newest available release! And it worked: I skipped two releases and jumped directly from *Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)* to *[Ubuntu 19.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.10_(Eoan_Ermine)) (Eoan Ermine)*!

Maybe it would have worked to upgrade Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) to Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) in one run.

Comment: This is the cleanest approach.

Comment: It's a pity that I can't mark the answer with `do-release-upgrade -p` the best, the simplest, forever topmost and the only one working :-)

Answer (score 8):

It appears the Karmic repositories are [no longer available](http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists.).

Since they are for a previous version of Ubuntu, you might consider removing them from your sources list.  Take a look at [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Removing_.26_Disabling_Repositories) for step-by-step.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the repositories under the "old-releases" server http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

And about how to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Thanks gajdipajti, I'm looking for it inside the package list, but cannot find the correct ".deb". My ubuntu already has "libsensors3", but all the packages ask me for the "libsensors4". I know the normal solution should be upgrade, but I cannot do it because the computer is dedicated to be used with a software that only runs on 9.10.

Comment: @Rorro:  Which software only runs on Ubuntu 9.10?

Answer (score 3):

There is an edge case - [apt-get claims 16.04 LTS does not exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921175/apt-get-claims-16-04-lts-does-not-exist) - where the old package (Vivid, in my case) was not in on the "old-releases" server. But apt-get could only find kernel and Google updates.

I am not sure exactly what my problem was because I had blindly followed the accepted answers `sed` command (never a smart move).

This did not work because Vivid was not in the "old-releases" archive but was still on the `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` mirror.

In that specific case, the solution was as follows:

```
sudo -i
edit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Carefully go through all the sources and discover one of them was old and wrong and had failed to be properly updated (or something). Or, as I did, search replace from `old-releases.ubuntu.com` to `gb.archive.ubuntu.com`. It then upgraded, without a problem, to the next release while I caught up on some reading.

So either:

1. There was a fault in my sources
2. The `gb.archive.unbuntu.com` mirror has an older set of releases.

The takeaway here is that while the majority of answers here may apply in some cases it would pay to be sure that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is correct before you nuke it for the "old-releases" archive.

You can figure out which of the archive or your mirror has the version you need by simply pointing a browser tab at the archive and question and looking for your version name in the folder list. Whichever one has your version, is the source you need to use.

Answer (score 3):

**18.10 to 19.10 Ubuntu upgrade**

**If you have EOL release and if you do not afraid of reinstalling your system from scratch or just without formatting this older system, than you could try it. It tried only of curiocity and for testing purposes. Not real hardware, but VM have been used for this. DO NOT USE IT ON PROD.** But strangely if you have EOL on prod.

Trying to correctly answer [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213466/how-to-configure-an-out-of-date-system-to-install-software-with-apt/1213482#1213482) I've installed Ubuntu 18.10 eol into VirtualBox VM.

- I changed current `/etc/apt/sources.list` to 18.04 Ubuntu's version:

  ```
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
  deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
  ```
- Changed `/etc/lsb-release` to:

  ```
  DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
  DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
  DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
  DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04 lts"
  ```
- `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo do-release-upgrade`

During upgrade it failed to restart different services and even rejected to reboot or shutdown correctly. I've powered the VM off and started it again.

It started without issues.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release && uname -a
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
Linux ubuntu18 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 31 20:24:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Testing:**
Applications are opened correctly. 
`/etc/apt/sources.list` have been generated with duplicates of eoan repositories, so I've removed excessive records and now it is:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

Installed `scribus`, `snap`, `mariadb-server`, `docker`, `openssh-server` using `sudo apt install` without issues.

Installed `gimp` using snap: `snap install gimp --classic` (Authentication prompt appeared and after password input installation started)

It looks like a usual stable 19.10 Ubuntu system upgraded correctly as my host is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was stuck in 19.04 for months because I didn't upgrades at time and I wasn't able to do the upgrade to 19.10 after that time. But the other day, Ubuntu automatically gives me the option to do a **Partial Upgrade** to 19.10 (maybe because I did a lot of stuff weeks ago, but sorry, I can't be sure the reason). So I did it and the result of `lsb_release -a` was Ubuntu 19.10. So I think I could be able to do another upgrade to 20.04.1, but isn't possible because 19.10 reached EOL.

The solution what I found today, 16 December 2020, to make an upgrade in Ubuntu 19.10 in EOL is to:

1. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Copy the following sources list (https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170) :

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse 
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner 
   deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
   ```
3. Paste it to your `sources.list` and disable with **`#`** the Eoan links.
4. In a terminal: `update-manager`. This will open the Software Updater window and check for updates and **upgrades**. Here is where I be able to make another **Partial Upgrade**, in this case, to 20.04.1LTS. Another `lsb_release -a` shows that I am in 20.04.1LTS.

[image]

I hope this will serve for someone, someday.

Merry Christmas to all.